# Can't run node.js app on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I run my node.js app on Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu 14.04)

On localhost, it works, but application not available on the internet by this address http://ec2-35-160-4-84.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3443/ where 3443 is my port.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to go to your Security groups on the server, and update the inbound rules to allow port 3443. I assume this would be a TCP connection so you need to update the Custom TCP put in the port and then choose which IP or if all you want to allow into the system.

To get to Security Groups .. go to your EC2 instance, then look on the left side where the menu is and you will see Security Groups listed. Click there, and make sure you are updating the Security Groups ***INBOUND*** rules for the right server.

Hope that works.

Comment: My pleasure @DenisWorker